# Jboss startup with "-g" option

Tags: jboss5.x, jboss-cache

Our application running on JBoss EAP and Jboss SOA Server.While starting up the jboss cache, the cache nodes are not shown, then its been told to start with "-g" option. Please let me know what is this option and its impact.

After using this option, its taking too much time to load cache nodes, since there is too many nodes to be read.

We also tried with different partition name, still the problem remains same.
nohup ./run.sh -c production -Djboss.partition.name "string"

Kindly help me to resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

-g is used to specify your partition name. Partitions are just another terminology used by JBoss for Clusters. So ideally any jboss node you start with the same value for -g or --partition will be on the same cluster provided they have the same multicast address.